# Using CSS Templates with Flask: Overriding "static system"

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm just starting out with Flask, and I was wondering what the best method for
dealing with how flask deals with static files when trying to use a premade CSS template.

Basically, I have downloaded a CSS template that I liked off the internet, but when if I simply drag the files into my flask application folder the CSS, JS, and image files do not work since they are not located in the static folder.

But if I move all the static files into the static folder, then I have to go through all the code and change the link urls, which is very time consuming.

The CSS Template I am using has an index.html that uses links like

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/style.css" >
```

I have set both the `static_folder = ""`
and the `static_url_path = ""` in my flask app and I have moved the css, js, and image folders from the downloaded template into the base folder for the application, but the links are still not working.

Is there a better way to deal with using premade CSS templates with flask? Can I override the need to put css and js and image files in the static folder somehow? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look at Flask class constuctor [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/) . The are optional parameters static_path

Comment: Changing the static path to "css" is probably a bad idea if you want to serve different static files later like Js or JSON. I would rewrite every template and use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/common.css') }}">` which is the standart way for flask apps.

Answer (score 1):

*(Sorry for opening this old post, but I'm on a badge hunt `:]`)*

There are several possible solutions, but the one I would recommend is to move the file `style.css` to folder `<server_root>/static/css/`.

Then create the flask app like `app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')`, what means that it still serves static files from the `static/` folder, but on path `/` (so `<server_root>/static/css/style.css` is served on `/css/style.css`).

With this setup, your links `href="/css/style.css"` will work.

---

However, it's strongly recommended to use `flask.url_for('endpoint', param='value')` instead of `/endpoint/url/value` both in code and templates (surrounded with `{{ ... }}`) for all URLs - static files (`'static', filename='css/style.css'`) and your own endpoints. So if your endpoint looks like this,

```
@app.route('/some/path/<variable>')
def some_endpoint(variable):
    # do something and return response...
```

... you can use `url_for('some_endpoint, variable='something')` no matter what the actual URL (`/some/path/something/` in this case) is. (Tested `python 3.6.7; flask 1.0.2`)